# Internal Server Error after Joomla update from 3.3.1 to 3.3.4

Tags: upgrade, internal-server-error, joomla3.3

I've upgraded my Joomla version from 3.3.1 to 3.3.4 for security issues and now I get an Internal Server Error. What should I do?

Comment: You could start by enabling **error_reporting** to Maximum: `System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting: Maximum`. If you don't have access to administrator panel you have to set `public $error_reporting = 'maximum';` in configuration.php.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to reset the permissions on the configuration panel provided by the provider.